# Adding setTimeout UL menu using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, menu, drop-down-menu, delay, settimeout

I am trying to add a delay to a drop down menu. I want the menu to stay visible for about two seconds after the cursor has moved away from it. Here is an example of my HTML.

```
<ul class="select">
  <li><a><b>Home</b></a></li>
  <li><a><b>Accommodation</b></a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li><a>Hotels</a></li>
      <li><a>Luxury Villas</a></li>
      <li><a>Apartments</a></li>
      <li><a>Hostels</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the css i am using.

## nav {

```
height:30px;
width: 904px;
position:relative;
font-family:arial, verdana, sans-serif;
font-size:13px;
z-index:500;
background-color: #666;
background: url(../images/sub-nav_04.jpg);
```

}

## nav .select {

margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; white-space:nowrap;
}

## nav li {

```
float:left;
```

}

## nav .select a {

```
display:block;
height:30px;
float:left;
text-decoration:none;
line-height:30px;
white-space:nowrap;
color:#333;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-right-style: dotted;
border-right-color: #666;
padding-right: 0;
padding-left: 15px;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 0px;
```

}

## nav .select1 a {

```
height: 30px;
line-height:30px;
cursor:pointer;
color:#fff;
background-color: #006;
background-image: url(../images/sub-nav2.jpg);
```

}

## nav .select a b {

display:block; padding:0 30px 0px 15px;
}

## nav .select li:hover a {

```
height: 30px;
line-height:30px;
cursor:pointer;
color:#fff;
background-color: #006;
background-image: url(../images/sub-nav2.jpg);  
z-index: 2000;
```

}

## nav .select li:hover a b {

```
display:block;
cursor:pointer;
padding-top: 0;
padding-right: 30px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 15px;
z-index: 2000;
```

}

## nav .sub {

display:none; margin:0; padding:0 0 0 0;list-style:none; background-color: #006;
}

## nav .sub li { background-color:#006;}

## nav .select li:hover .sub {

height:30px; display:block; position:absolute; float:left; width:904px; top:28px; left:0; text-align:center; background-color: #006; background:url(../images/sub-nav2.jpg); z-index: 980;
}

## nav .select li:hover .sub li a {

```
display:block;
height:30px;
line-height:30px;
float:left;
white-space:nowrap;
color: #FFF;
font-size:12px;
font-weight: bold;
border-top-width: 0px;
border-right-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-right-style: dotted;
border-right-color: #666;
padding-right: 16px;
padding-left: 16px;
margin-right: 0;
margin-bottom: 0;
margin-left: 7;
z-index: 1000;
```

}

## nav .select li:hover .sub li a:hover {

color: #000; background:#fff; border-top: 0px; line-height:30px; height: 30px; background:url(../images/sub-nav3.jpg); z-index: 990;
}

Comment: Are you having trouble with making it appear as a list? Do you have any JavaScript so far? What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

A (sorta) good example of this can be found [here](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/coda-popup-bubbles/)

```
var hideDelayTimer = null;
$('.select').mouseenter(function () {
  $(this).children('.sub').slideDown().mousenter(function () {
    if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
  }).mouseleave(function () {
    if (hideDelayTimer) clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
    hideDelayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
      hideDelayTimer = null;
      $(this).slideUp();
    }, 2 * 1000);
  });
});
```

If you need some help with positioning, you could do something like this:

```
$('.sub').each(function () {
  var parent = $(this).parent();
  var parentOffset = parent.offset();
  $(this).css({
    left: parentOffset.left + parent.width(), 
    top: parentOffset.top
  });
});
```

Comment: See http://jsfiddle.net/V7MwK/ for an updated copy, although still not quite working..

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tried the code, but it still won't work. Do you need me to show you the CSS i have used?

Comment: That would help. Just got back from holidays.

Comment: I have added the CSS to the original post above.

Comment: Is `nav` the parent div name?

Comment: Hey! Got it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/V7MwK/1/ You need to sort out the styling though. P.S. I removed all `li:hover`s because my javascript controls them.